# Id não aceitando valor asp mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Pessoal estou tentando fazer uma logica de login mas de uma forma sem usar as outras tecnologias do asp mvc 5

```
[HttpPost]


[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public ActionResult Cadastro(Fornecedor fornecedo, int? id )

{

    var acesso = db.Fornecedor.Any(m => m.Codigo == id);

    if (acesso == false)

    {

        db.Fornecedor.Add(fornecedo);

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("a");



    }

    if(acesso == true){
                ViewData["erro"] = "Mensagem de Erro";
                return View();
            }
            return View("z");
        }
```

Quando eu cadastro com mesmo codigo ele da um erro que já existe esse codigo mas quando eu vejo se tem algum dado do id para null.

Comment: Robson, o id está permitindo null devido ao `int?`, acho que nem deveria permitir. Oque está acontecendo é que sua PK id aceita null, mas já foi feito um cadastro com o valor null e por ser PK ele não aceitará outro. Seu id sempre está indo null, mas com apenas oque postou não da pra saber o por quê.

Comment: Parece que ficou faltando um pedaço do final da pergunta.. mas qndo eu vejo se tem algum dado do id para null... ? E não entendi: está implementando uma lógica de login sem outras tecnologias num cadastro de fornecedor?

Comment: Na verdade eu consegui achar o erro,no codigo estou comparando o ID com m.Codigo , porem eu deveria comprar o fornecedo(minha tabela) com o m.Codigo ,solução ficou assim  var acesso = db.Fornecedor.Any(m => m.Codigo != fornecedo.Codigo);